# Multi GPUs pytorch prediction

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, gpu, multi-gpu

I am trying to use multiple GPUs for a code that is already running correctly for one GPU.
I did those modifications to make it able to di multiple GPUs:

```
classifier = AnnotationCNN.load_from_checkpoint(classifier_ckpt,normalizer_ckpt=normalizer_ckpt)
classifier=classifier.eval()
    
**device = torch.device("cuda" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu")**
classifier = classifier.to(torch.float16).to(device)
**classifier= nn.DataParallel(classifier)**


dataset = InitImageTifDataset(
                data_root=data_root,
                level=level,
                region_width=region_width,
                region_height=region_height,
                crop_size=crop_size,
                image_dir=image_dir,
                image_name=image_name,
                channels=channels
            )

        dl = DataLoader(dataset, batch_size=5, shuffle=False, num_workers=5)
        for i,(img,mean_stddev,filename) in enumerate(dl):
            mask = mean_stddev > 20

            img=img[torch.nonzero(mask)]
            if img.nelement() != 0 :
                **tensor=img[:,0,0,:,:,:].to(device).to(torch.float16).to(device)**
                *_,preds = classifier(tensor)*
```

But I have the following error:

```
RuntimeError: Expected tensor for argument #1 'output' to have the same device as tensor for argument #5 'weight'; but device 0 does not equal 1 (while checking arguments for batch_norm_cuda)
```

I am pretty sure the error is coming from the DataLoader that has not being adapted to multi GPUs. How can I fixe it, Thank you.

Comment: I have also been struggling with multi-GPUs on pl. An easy multi-gpu setup is what makes pl appealing on paper. But after several days trying to fix all kinds of issues. I am seriously reconsidering the value of pl.